Is micro-world non-deterministic and macro-world deterministic?
In general, can we say that micro-world is non-deterministic and macro-world is deterministic?
We know where a thrown stone will land, so why do some people say that the macro world is non-deterministic? Just because we can't measure something 100% accurately, that doesn't mean that the object is not there where nature's rules determine it to be.

Chaos theory applies in the macro world just fine. Can you predict with great certainty where a falling leaf will land?

@JonCuster Chaos is deterministic , just very sensitive to initial conditions. If that is not case we will not know weather forcast...

But we don't know the weather forecast. I know it'll still be hot out in fifteen minutes, and I know it will be cooler tonight. The folks with the huge dataset and the supercomputers predict that it'll be rainy next weekend, but that prediction is fuzzy. The details of the daily forecast in two months is just as chaotic as the falling leaf, which (probably) will land under or near the tree. Only in aggregate can we make long-term weather forecasts with confidence.

@rob Of course we dont know weather forecast, because we never know  initial position of every air particle in earth atmosphere. We  dont even know 1% of initial condition of atmosphere.

Correct. But as your answers below explain, it's impossible to know positions and momenta to a combined precision better than $\sigma_x\sigma_p\gtrsim\hbar$. That intrinsic uncertainty, plus classical chaos, destroys any hope of true determinism.

@rob Sabine, Brain Green etc  dont agree with this... If we dont all nature rules (and never will know) that dont mean this rules dont exist.. Randomness=magic

I don't want to abuse our comment system by getting into a debate about the opinions of people who are not here to state their own minds. But consider the possibility that you have set up a false dichotomy.

@rob What mean that world is non deterministic? What that mean for engineering, design etc, how we make staff that works if everything is random?  Is everything is random how arrow hit the target, etc?? non determinism for macro world is total non sense

Technically classical mechanics classical mechanics is a 100% deterministic theory. But when looking at more complicated systems it will get very chaotic very fast, which means your deterministic trajectory will depend very strongly on the initial conditions. That means if you want to make a prediction with sufficient accuracy for the trajectory in the arbitrarily far future you need exact initial conditions. But here the quantum uncertenties tell you that you can’t know your initial conditions arbitrarily exact. So chaos theory effectively transfers your quantum indeterminism into the macroscopic world if looking at time wise sufficiently long trajectories. Because the small difference causes by quantum uncertenties will be transferred into macroscopic differences eventually, if your system is sufficiently chaotic.
So in conclusions that means, that if the "micro-world" is non-deterministic the "macro-world" is also non-deterministic.

Why theoretical physicists, Sabine, Brain Green etc dont agree with this? What about Bohmian mechanics?

@22flower I don‘t understand what you try to tell me. The people you mention in your opinion don’t agree on what exactly? What do you think there should be about Bohmian mechanics?

They consider world deterministic

@22flower First of all I am pretty sure it is the mainstream opinion in theoretical physics that the measurement process in quantum mechanics is truly random. Sabine even states that in the video you linked in your comment to another answer. So your statement “They consider world deterministic” is wrong.

Secondly I never stated that the world is not deterministic I just said that if you accept that the microscopic world is non-determenistic, which might not be the case if you want to construct some theory with funky hidden variables, who’s values depend on the kind of measurement you are making, a sufficiently chaotic macroscopic system will also show effective indeterminism at large times.

Roughly, if you consider the early matter wave approach by de Broglie, the wavelength $\lambda$ is inversely proportional to the momentum $p$ which in turn is proportional to the mass: $$\lambda = \frac{h}{p}=\frac{h}{mv}\sim \frac{1}{m}$$
Massive objects thus have a small de Broglie wavelength. The probability distribution is then much more sharply peaked. For macroscopic objects the peak is so sharp that the position of an object is known with a very high precision.

But we know where thrown stone will land, so why some people say macro world is non deterministic?

@22flower We know where a thrown stone will land to a high degree of precision - but not to an infinite degree of precision because it has a small but non-zero de Broglie wavelength.

@gandalf61 so you dont agree with this ?https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zpU_e3jh_FY

@22flower - Sabine Hossenfelder often takes controversial stands. In this case, I can't argue her point, but I will not consider the question settled until we know more about minds. See my answer and comments to How is energy "stored in an electric field"?. Robert Sapolsky also makes Hossenfelder's point with more details about the mind. Do We Have Free Will? | Robert Sapolsky & Andrew Huberman

Sapolsky's wonderful online course from Stanford on Human Behavioral Biology is well worth watching. Lots about the inner workings of the mind.

@22flower To reach her conclusion about free will Hossenfelder assumes that all physical laws are deterministic. But we know this not true in quantum mechanics - apparently God does play dice with the universe. So Hossenfelder's conclusion is based on a false premise.

@gandalf61 Sabine didnt say that quantum is deterministic. There is no way how "you" can tell your neurons what to do, neuros decide what you do. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wSYcUl2TXDc “In the mind there is no absolute, or free, will, but the mind is determined to will this or that by a cause which is also determined by another, and this again by another, and so to infinity”

@22flower "so you dont agree with this" It is rather bad behavior to ask a question, get an answer answering that question, and then start a discussion in the comments about a different question you didn't include in the question in the first place. Since others have already posted answers to this question, it should be asked as a separate question.

@22flower In the future, if you wish to ask about a specific source, it should be included in the original question. It is undesirable behavior to first ask a generic question along the lines of "is X correct?", then ask in the answer comments "but source Y said otherwise", when you didn't even mention any sources in the question in the first place. You should just ask your real question, which is about the source itself, to begin with.

The world is not perfectly deterministic. But it isn't totally random either. Sometimes you can use the present to predict the future very well. Sometimes not so well.
One source of non-determinism is quantum uncertainty. We are used to thinking of a particle as a point with a perfectly defined position and momentum that we cannot measure perfectly. This leads to a perfectly defined trajectory.
The reality is that there is a range of positions where the particle might be. It does not have a position. Likewise there is a range of momenta the particle might have. Furthermore, if one range is small, the other must necessarily be big. This is expressed by the Uncertainty Principle, $\Delta x \Delta p > \hbar$.
These uncertainties lead to a range of trajectories the particle might have. You cannot predict exactly what trajectory the particle will take. But you do have some information. You can predict probabilities.
The limits on precision of position and momentum are the same size for all objects, big and small. But the effect is more noticeable for small objects.
You might want to find the trajectory of an electron orbiting a nucleus. The nucleus attracts the electron and tries to keep it very close. A small range of positions means a large range of momenta. An electron that might have a large momentum isn't likely to stay very close to a nucleus for long. This tends to keep the electron farther away. The size of an atom is determined by these competing tendencies. The range of positions an electron might have is the size of the atom. The electron doesn't have an orbit. It just has a range of positions and momenta near the nucleus. If you measure the position, it might be any one of them and it might be going in any direction. This is described as an electron cloud.
A stone has uncertainties the same size. If you determine the position of the stone with a precision of an atomic diameter, the stone will necessarily have a range of momenta as big as the electron does. This means if you throw the stone, the uncertainty of momentum would affect the trajectory as much as if an electron bumped it off course.
Quantum uncertainty limits the precision of macroscopic trajectories, but the effect is so small that we cannot detect it. It was not discovered until people studied subatomic particles.

If we cant meassure something 100% accurate, that doesnt mean  that object is not there where nature rules determine to be

@22flower This is what is known as theory containing "local hidden variables". It has been experimentally verified that nature does not have such hidden variables. See Bell test for more information.

The question asks whether the world is nondeterministic and your answer is that quantum mechanics (including wave function collapse) is nondeterministic.   That is correct but not actually responsive to the question, to which the answer is "we have no idea".

@WillO - I have always heard that quantum mechanics and its non-determinancy is a good model of the world. Are you saying this is not so?

@mmesser314 :  I'm sure it's an excellent model.  I'm equally sure it's a model.

@mmesser314 Stone is made of particles that behave random(for we know now) but that doesnt mean the stone can fall in every position,  he will land at only one position depend on his initial conditions..

@WillO Stone will land at only one position depend on initial conditions, he simply cant land at every random position. so non determinism and real objects for me is unlogical
